# spring 3 @schedule issue

Tags: spring

I have two apps both use @Scheduled annotation. And both has their own application context xml which contains `<task:annotation-driven />`. Now when I deploy both apps, I am getting this exceptions

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context.

Can somebody explain why I am getting it?

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by deploying both apps - are these two totally separate web applications or are you combining them together in some way (say into a same war) before deploying. Are you importing one spring context into another etc.

Comment: I suggest to move `<task:annotation-driven />` from servlet contexts of applications to shared application context.

Comment: No both apps different and no. one is importing context from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Even I have encountered such a problem. But with `<tx:annotation-driven/>`

I think the problem is in configuring the xml. Got the app running after some trial and error method.

I had configured like this for  `<tx:annotation-driven/>`

`<beans xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
         xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  </beans>`

But after changing this as below the exception got resolved

`<beans xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
         xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx

                              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"
  </beans>`

I think you can resolve the problem by configuring the spring "task" like this

`<beans xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
         xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd"
  </beans>`

Hope this might help, Thanks